# how to change date format in bootstrap datepicker input field for japanese calender

Tags: c#, html, datetime, calendar, cjk

I am using Datepicker for input field . The code is :

```
<div class='input-group date w250' id='idStartDate'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="@Resources.StringStartDate" @*data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD A h:mm"*@/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

And the script code for picking the calender is:

```
$('#idStartDate').datetimepicker({
    icons: {
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
        down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
    },
    maxDate: new Date(),
    language: userLang,
    format: "YYYY/MM/DD A hh:mm"
});
```

Here the user Language picks the browser language.But when i give the format as "YYYY/MM/DD A hh:mm" it japanesse calender displays as 2018/10/29 午後 05:20.But my expected result is 2018/10/29 PM 05:20.Where am i doing a mistake.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please add relevant tags like "jQuery", "Razor"  "ASP.NET" (if you are using them)

Comment: By using `language` setting, the `AM`/`PM` indicator will follow default configuration of current language in use. If you want to define custom format (e.g. Japanese date format with English indicator), it may be necessary to override existing one.